# onclick event does not run jQuery function

Tags: jquery, function, onclick

I have an html file which is correctly linked to a js file (and also the jquery library file).

```
<input type="button" onclick="practice();" id="intro_next_button" value="Practice"/>
```

Inside the js file:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    function practice(){
        alert("WORKS");
    }
});
```

This runs if function practice is outside of the `$(window).load(function()`, but not when it is inside of it. There are many similar questions to this, but I have not found one that is specifically about an `onclick event` only not working inside of a jquery `$(window).load(function()`.

Comment: because the function is in the block scope of onload and is not global. Why is it defined in the onload? Move it out.

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression that I should put everything in the onload function in order to make sure it works.

Comment: That would not be the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because anything defined (i.e. via keywords function or var) inside a function block applies that block as it's scope. So if you make a variable, x, inside the block you won't have the value outside there.

```
var x = 2;
function test() { var x = 5; }
console.log(x);
```

Prints 2.

These are also competing styles. Typically if you use window.onload or the "improved" jQuery $(document).ready you bind events in the body of the function.

```
$("#intro_next_button").click(function() { alert("WORKS"); });
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is defining a function inside the function that is passed to load() as a parameter.

onclick is looking for practice() in the window scope.

Why you want to DEFINE the function when page is loaded? to wait until is loaded so the user can click it?
If so, try this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  window.practice = function(){
    alert("WORKS");
  }
});
```

Comment: How would I call the `window.practice` function in the onclick? I tried `onclick="practice()"` and `onclick="window.practice()"`

Comment: when you define something in window, its basically global scope. No need to call window.functionname()
Basically EVERYTHING you define without scope is defined in window. :)
Try in this code:
function test(){};
console.log('what?', window.test);

Answer (score 1):

In this case your function is visible only within the anonimous function you defined in `load`. You should attach an onclick event to the button using the jquery `click` inside the `load` (and also remove `onclick` attribute):

```
  $('#buttonid').click(function(){practice();});
```

Comment: If not mine, a hybrid from ours could be ok also:
$(document).load(function(){
$('#buttonid').click(function(){practice();});
});